# How do you reference an android application project class in a library project?

Tags: android

I have an application project and a library project. The only difference between application projects will be a constants source file and resources. When I add resources to the application project they are pulled in at compile time and replace the lib project resources (normal behaviour). I have a package that contains the constants.java file in the src folder of the application project but this does not replace the constants.java in the lib project at compile time. The library project contains a number of files that depend on the constants file but I want to alter the constants file for each application project. What is the best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: you can check this link if it helps. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html. your question is confusing